# Easiest way to test iOS 4.2.1 with Xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode

A similar question has been asked in the past, but this is a moving target and I haven't found a tenable solution. I am working on an app for enterprise deployment and the customer has a large number of iPads running iOS 4.2.1 in the field that I need to test for.

How can I best test on 4.2.1? The latest version the apple seems to allow is 4.3 for the simulator, and there does not seem to be any way to downgrade an iPad to 4.2.1

I am currently running 10.7.3 with Xcode 4.3.1.

Comment: What is the problem on looking for an old xCode version with that simulator on it?

Comment: xcode 3.2.5 (with the ios 4.2 sdk) will not run on lion.

Answer (score 0):

The below link answers the question. Basically, the limitation of Xcode 3.x not running on lion is artificial and imposed by apple. You can get around this by simply enabling command line installs and launching the installer from terminal.

http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/8064949186/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion-redux

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install Simulator 4.2 on Xcode 4.3.1. Basically, you need to get some older SDK (4.3 will work) find the package `iPhoneSimulatorSDK4_2.pkg` in the hidden `Packages` folder. Install it into some temporary folder, locate `iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk` there. And move it inside Xcode.app bundle to `/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs` then restart Xcode.

It is described in details [here](http://wicharek.name/en/blog/how-to-install-ios-simulator-4-2-in-xcode-4-3-1).